when call a function out of eventlistener function an error appears

click Butten to initialize  2. click the square and the error appear
Why only in func  clickCell()  it's not possible to call func(2)?

I have reduced the code as much as I can and hope anybody knows a soluten.


function initClass() {
    new Class_1(0);
}

class Class_1 {

    constructor(sfNr) {
        this.sfNr = sfNr;
        this.func2(200);    // works
        this.func3(300);    // works
        
        this.func1();
    }

    func1() {
        document.getElementById('cellid_1').addEventListener("click", this.clickCell);
        this.func2(15);  
    };

    clickCell() {
        this.func2(300);    // don't work???
        console.log("clickCell");
    };

    func2(p2) {
        console.log("func2 reached!  p2= " + p2);
    };
    
    func3(p3) {
        console.log("func3 reached!  p3= " + p3);
        this.func2(400);
    };

};
    <div>
        <div class="clear_numbers">
            <button id="btn_p1" class="btn_p1_p4" onclick="initClass()">1. Click</button>
        </div>
<br>
<style>
.cell {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>

<div id="cellid_1" class="cell">2. Click</div>  
        



Thank You
